# Android using TextWatcher to replace words

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `editText`, that you write in it something then when u click next .. the text u wrote gets written into another editText ..
It's working perfectly ..
But I want to use textWatcher to replace some letters..

Example: How do I make the S to be $
or the O to be @

**UPDATE:**

```
    final EditText First = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFirst);
    String strFirst = First.getText().toString();
    final TextView done = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    String strDone = done.getText().toString();
    Button Trans = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTrans);

        Trans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //First EditText
                if (First.getText().toString().equals("John")) {
                    done.setText("JOHN");
                } else {
                if (First.getText().toString().equals("Ahmed")) {
                    done.setText("AHMED");
                } else  {
                done.setText(First.getText());
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    });

        First.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)    {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            done.setText(First.getText().toString().replaceAll("S", "$"));
            }
            });
```

my code will type what you wrote in the EditText to a Large TextView below .. when I press the button `Trans` it sets the text which you wrote but I want to replace some letters example S to $ .. when I type S nothing happens .. just S it don't gets to be $ ..

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the Textwatcher to your editText then do something like

```
editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("S", "$"));
```

Here is the textWatcher with code applied

```
    final EditText First = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFirst);
    String strFirst = First.getText().toString();
    final TextView done = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    String strDone = done.getText().toString();
    Button Trans = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTrans);

        Trans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //First EditText
                if (First.getText().toString().equals("John")) {
                    done.setText("JOHN");
                } else {
                if (First.getText().toString().equals("Ahmed")) {
                    done.setText("AHMED");
                } else  {
                done.setText(First.getText());
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    });

        First.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)    {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String text = First.getText().toString();
                text = text.replace('s', 'd'); // Any of the diffrent replace methods should work.
                text = text.replace('S', '$'); // This uses the char replace method. Note, the ' quotations
                text = text.replace('O', '@');
                text = text.replace('o', '@');
                done.setText(text);
            }
        });
```

Its possible that the error resided in the fact you are getting the old string again, and applying `text.replace` on it. Rather than the modified string. I would have expected it to have got the new string, but setText doesnt seem to fire immediately.

So if you get the string into a variable, then apply all your changes. Then put it back to your text box it will work fine. (`I have tested and working code here Pasted above`)

Comment: Your going to have to be more specific, What part is going wrong. Have you tried fixing these errors. Have you `import`ed any neccessary packages.

Comment: the prob was with overRides .. I removed them .. this is the code now http://pastebin.com/uV7ribXD it does nothing.. note* Trans is button clicked so text in Edittext one ( First ) gets written in EditText two ( done )

Comment: you should really be using `else if{` rather than `else { if{`. But thats not the problem. Your button sets the listener. So press the button, the edit the text. Try taking the text watcher outside of the onclick listener and see if it works. If answers are helpful in anyway, consider upvoting. :)

Comment: @JohnJr.South I wrote a test app, and tested code. see above.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work .. when I type S or O it's the same what I type I get .. but when I type John I get JOHN ( the text watcher doesn't work )

Comment: It's okay, I added the textWatcher in the onClick and now everything is working fine. ACCEPTED :D.. thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

When putting in the value of your first EditText into the value of the second EditText, you can use Java's `replace()` function for Strings. For example, the following code prints "$X@$$".

```
String value = "SXOSS";
String newValue = value.replace("S", "$"); //replaces all instances of S with $
newValue = newValue.replace("O", "@"); //replaces all instances of O with @
System.out.println(newValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried       First.getText().toString().replaceAll("Z", "E"); .. but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you make sure to do `First.setText( First.getText().toString().replaceAll("Z", "E") )`?